# $.ajax does not read echo from .php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, echo

I am trying to get ajax to read and post a echo of a php file into the search suggenstion box but it seems not to work. Any suggestions where is mistake?

(*code updated to be without simple mistakes, but still not giving a wanted result*)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = $('#start').position().left;
    var top = $('#start').position().top;
    var width = $('#start').width();

    $("#suggestionbox").css("left", left+40).css("top", top+60).css("width", width);

    $("#start").keyup(function(){
    var value =  $("#start").val();
    if(value != ''){
            $.ajax(
                {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'search.php',
            data: {value: value},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) { 
                debugger;  
                $("#suggestionbox").html(data);
                alert(data); 
                }, //success    
            error: function(){
                alert("nothing");
            } //error
            }); //$.post
        } //if
        }); //keyup
}); //ready
```

**php**

```
<?php echo 'Working!'; ?>
```

**form and div in html file**

```
<form class="inputForm" action="#">
<fieldset>
<input name='start' id="start" class="inputStart" type="text"  placeholder="Start" onfocus="(this.value == 'Start') && (this.value = '')" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Start';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Start') {this.value = '';}" />
<input name='end' id="End" class="inputFinish" type="text" placeholder="End" onfocus="(this.value == 'End') && (this.value = '')" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'End';}" />
 <select name="count">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input class="inputDate" type="text" data-type="date" id="datepicker" value="date" />
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value=" " />
</fieldset>
</form> 

<div id="suggestionbox">
</div>
```

*Note:* php file is in the same folder as js.

**Update:**

```js
 $("#start").keyup(function(){
   var value =  $("#start").val();
 if(value != ''){
   $.ajax(
    {
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'search.php',
   data: {value: value},
   dataType: 'html', 
   success: function(data) { 
    debugger;
    $("#suggestionbox").html(data);
    alert(data); 
    }, //success 
   error: function(){
    alert('error');
   } //error
   }); //$.ajax
  } //if
      }); //keyup
```

Above shown (repaired) code doesn't put anything into the #suggestionbox field and alert output is full code of php file:

```
<?php 
echo 'Working!'; 
?>
```

Comment: it's not working because you tried on document ready. after document .ready write $('.searchbutton').click(function(){ and wrap all your code inside it. and then try by clicking the button.

Comment: Also you missed dataType:html in your ajax call

Comment: 2 other misspellings: It should be type: 'POST' in the Ajax call, and in your date input it should be data-type="date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look in the console for any Javascript errors? In any case, this works (it's pretty much your above code verbatim): http://jsfiddle.net/5jzskmyg/1/

I see that you have now put your code inside a `$(document).ready()` callback, so I would suggest putting in logging statements to make sure everything is being loaded correctly (perhaps the script itself is not loading). For example:

```
console.log(1);

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(2);

    var left = $('#start').position().left;
    var top = $('#start').position().top;
    var width = $('#start').width();

    $("#suggestionbox").css("left", left+40).css("top", top+60).css("width", width);

    $("#start").keyup(function(){
        console.log(3);

        var value =  $("#start").val();
        if(value != ''){
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'search.php',
                data: {value: value},
                dataType: 'html', 
                success: function(data) { 
                    console.log(4);

                    debugger;
                    $("#suggestionbox").html(data);
                    alert(data); 
                    }, //success    
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                } //error
            }); //$.ajax
        } //if
    }); //keyup
}); //ready
```

Comment: it's meant to be as a breakpoint for the FireBug. Anyhow if I remove it, it does not change anything in the final result. Still suggestionbox is empty.

Comment: I updated my answer...try those logging statements and if you're still not sure of the problem, let us know which numbers got logged.

Comment: I tried that and all the places where log numbers are are passing nicely. Can't it be somthing with connecting to php file?? as I have already before updated the alert is returning full php code from the file including the <?php and end line ?>

Comment: Ah, I missed that....yes in that case, your server is not parsing the PHP file correctly. What happens if you go to search.php directly in your browser? Is the server running Apache and if so, have you checked that the PHP module is loaded correctly?

Comment: it was a php module not working properly. Absolutely missed that. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

The input fields in your form do not have a name attribute.

```
<form class="inputForm" action="#">
<fieldset>
<input name='start' id="start" class="inputStart" type="text"  placeholder="Start" onfocus="(this.value == 'Start') && (this.value = '')" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Start';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Start') {this.value = '';}" />
<input name='ciel' id="ciel" class="inputFinish" type="text" placeholder="End" onfocus="(this.value == 'End') && (this.value = '')" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'End';}" />
 <select name="count">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input class="inputDate" type="text" dtat-type="date" id="datepicker" value="date" />
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value=" " />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and I'm not sure about jQuery but it looks like there is a typo there - you use `typo:'POST'` - should this not be `type:'POST'`?

Comment: and also alert.("nothing"); - dot after alert. Looks like drunk-coding :)

Comment: yes, the typo was there. Anyhow after the repair it did not change the behavior - the field #suggestionbox does not get the value given in php's echo

Answer (score 0):

In the end the very last bothering thing was PHP module. Wasn't working properly, but it is repaired now and it is running beautifly.